How to Show/Hide rows in google sheets using a script?
I'm trying to make a calendar. I want rows 2-37 hidden if someone presses a shape in January,  39-74 if they press it in February etc. The script should take into account the sheet as well. So it only hides rows 2-37 on the active sheet not the sheet next to it.
A link or checkbox would be better than a shape but not sure if that's possible.
Here's the spreadsheet
current attempts
function toggleRowVisibility(startRow, endRow) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

 for (var i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
var row = sheet.getRange(i + ':' + i);

if (row.isHidden()) {
  row.setHidden(false); // Unhide the row if it's currently hidden
} else {
  row.setHidden(true); // Hide the row if it's currently visible
}
}} toggleRowVisibility('2:37');

function toggleRows() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

for (var i = 2; i <= 37; i++) {
var row = sheet.getRange(i, 1);

if (sheet.isRowHidden(i)) {
  sheet.showRows(i); // If row is hidden, show it
} else {
  sheet.hideRows(i); // If row is visible, hide it
}}}


Show/Hide rows in google sheets using a script
Assigning parameters in Assign Script is not possible but here is the modified version of your code.
// Toggle Shape Button Assigned Script
function toggleRowVisibilityJanuary() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(2) ? sheet.showRows(2, 36) : sheet.hideRows(2, 36);
} 

I use Ternary condition to check if the Row 2 is hidden and return a boolean if it is true then it will Show Rows from Row 2 to 36 and if it's false then it will Hide Rows Row 2 to 36.

Here's the output


Reference:

Class Sheet



If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer

Minor correction: if you want to show/hide rows 2 to 37, you need to write showRows(2, 36) and hideRows(2, 36).

@MoreHorseThanAMan Thank you for the correction, I updated the description and code above.

Several insights:

Are those two different versions of your function? Your code is not entirely clear.
I'm not sure what you mean by row.isHidden(), row.setHidden(), etc; but those methods do not exist. Or rather, they are not named that way: isRowHiddenByFilter(rowNumber), showRows(rowNumber, numberOfRows) and hideRows(rowNumber, numberOfRows) do exist in the Sheet class.
You need not loop through the rows, since you can (un)hide a whole range of rows directly.
I strongly suggest you use row numbers (as in the second version of your function) instead of the A1 notation.

Might I suggest that you read the documentation: Documentation.
Here is an outline of what you want to do:
function toggleRowsVisibility(startRow, endRow) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(startRow)) {
    sheet.showRows(startRow, endRow-startRow+1);
  } else {
    sheet.hideRows(startRow, endRow-startRow+1);
  }
} 

